# Windows 7 / Media Center lock problem

Tags: windows, windows-media-center, media, media-center

we have a Win7 with Media Center that is connected to a large screen. It displays a corporate slideshow near the coffeemachine.

When the computer is started it automatically logs in and starts the slideshow.

The problem is that on irregular time intervals (once a day, some days not) the slideshow stops and it switches to the login screen and shows which user is logged on.

We don't know why this is happening. We first thought someone on the network was trying to open RDC connection to the machine, because it is the same sympthon like when you take over a machine by RDC with a different user, but nobody is doing that.

Screensaver is disabled, energy settings "always on"

Anybody ideas why this is happening?

Comment: have you configured the system to either reject RDC connections or even better to only accept incoming RDC connections from a trusted group of specific IP's with the firewall? Also is this occurring when an admin logs into the system and then disconnects?

Comment: Hi gruntled, thanks for your comment, I disabled RDC connections and it was still happening. However I have found one option in the energy settings about requiring a password after sleep/standby. The energy settings are always on, so it should not matter, but I deselected this option anyway and now it seems to be solved(or at least it has not happened in the last 24 hours)